# Computing the total curvature

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $C$ be the curve in $\Bbb{R}^2$ given by $(t-\sin t,1-\cos t)$ for $0 \le t \le 2 \pi$. I want to find the total curvature of $C$.

I found it brutally by finding the curvature $k(t)$, and then reparametrize it by arc-length $s$, and then $\int_0^Lk(t(s))ds$, where $L=8$ is the lenght of $C$.

I found that the answer is $\pi$. But is there any way to compute it easily? The above computation was somewhat hard, and I guess that there maybe some easy methods(maybe something like Gauss-Bornet, or how much the angle of tangent vector has changed)

Comment: Gobi, did you ever get around solving this problem? I have to compute the total curvature of the unit sphere $S^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: @Lays Use the Gauss-Bonnet theorem. And I don't know if there is an easy way to compute it directly.

Answer (score 3):

At $t = 0$, the limiting value (from the right) of the unit tangent points vertically upward. At $t = 2\pi$, the limiting value (from the left) of the unit tangent points vertically downward. The total curvature is the angle through which the tangent rotates along the curve, namely $\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

Length: $s(2 \pi) = \int\limits_0^{2\pi} ||\dot{c}(t)||dt =  \int\limits_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{2(1-cos(t))}dt=8$.

Curvature: A formula to compute the curvature is $\frac{1}{\rho} = ||c''(s)||$ (at least if the used parameter is $s$).

Answer (score 1):

If $\gamma (t) $ is a regular space curve, its curvature is
$\kappa =||\gamma'' \times \gamma'||/||\gamma' ||^3 $.

Computation:

$\kappa'= (1-cost,sint,0), \kappa''= (sint,cost,0)$.

$||\gamma''(t) \times \gamma'(t)||= 1-cost$, $||\gamma'(t)||=2(1-cost)$.

$\int \kappa(s) ds = \int \frac{||\gamma''(t) \times \gamma'(t)||}{||\gamma'(t) ||^3}||\gamma'(t) ||dt = \int \frac{||\gamma''(t) \times \gamma'(t)||}{||\gamma'(t) ||^2}dt   =\int^{2 \pi}_{0} \frac{1-cost}{2(1-cost)}= \pi$

Answer (score 0):

A simpler answer is as follows: given the natural equation for a curve in the form of $\kappa(s)$, it can be shown that the tangent angle is given by

$$\theta=\int \kappa (s) ds \ \ \ \text{or} \ \ \  \kappa (s)=\frac{d\theta}{ds}$$

Thus from the definition of curvature used here, we obtain

$$K=\int_{s_1}^{s_2}\kappa(s)ds=\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}d\theta=\theta_2-\theta_1$$

In the present example, you will find $K=-\pi$, where the minus sign is due to the curve unwinding in the clockwise direction.